# Prove equality between product of 3 combinations

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Prove the following:
$$\binom{n-1}{k-1}\binom{n}{k+1}\binom{n+1}{k}=\binom{n-1}{k}\binom{n}{k-1}\binom{n+1}{k+1}$$
Originally, my idea was to use the property $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-1}{k}$ on each of the combinations but it didn't seem to get me far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just plug in the definition of the binomial coefficient.
$$\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)! (n-k)!} \frac{n!}{(k+1)!(n-k-1)!} \frac{(n+1)!}{k! (n+1-k)!}=  \frac{(n-1)!}{k!(n-1-k)!} \frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k+1)!} \frac{(n+1)!}{(k+1)!(n-k)!}$$

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't even take into consideration that it would be this simple... Thanks.